# XSLT Error : The attribute cannot be added after child nodes or before an element is produced; it will be ignored

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

**XML:**

```
       <xyz>
            <param name="test" value="center at &quot;St.&quot; francisco ">
       </xyz>
```

Above is my XML with "XYZ" as root tag.

Below is my XSLT

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <!-- Identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template match="xyz">

        <vce>

            <xsl:apply-templates
                select="node()[not(self::added-source | self::param)] | @*" />

            <xsl:call-template name="param-template" />


            <added-sources>
                <xsl:for-each select="added-source">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </added-sources>
        </vce>

    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="param-template">


        <xsl:for-each select="param">

            <xsl:variable name="paramNameValue">
                <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="paramValue">
                <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
            </xsl:variable>


            <xsl:choose>

                  <!--  When response has one line feeds --> 
                <xsl:when test="contains($paramValue, '&#10;')">

                    <xsl:variable name="modParamValue">
                        <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
                            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$paramValue" />
                            <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&#10;'" />
                            <xsl:with-param name="with" select="' '" />
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:variable>

                    <xsl:call-template name="param-template" />

                    <param>
                        <xsl:attribute name="name">
                                 <xsl:value-of select="$paramNameValue" />
                              </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                 <xsl:value-of select="$modParamValue" />
                              </xsl:attribute>
                    </param>
                </xsl:when>



                <!--  when param value tag has quotes  -->
                <xsl:when test="contains($paramValue, '&quot;')">

                <xsl:variable name="modParamValue">
                        <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
                            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$paramValue" />
                            <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&quot;'" />
                            <xsl:with-param name="with" select="' '" />
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:variable>
                     <xsl:call-template name="param-template" />
                       <param>
                     <xsl:attribute name="name">
                                 <xsl:value-of select="$paramNameValue" />
                              </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                 <xsl:value-of select="$modParamValue" />
                              </xsl:attribute>
                      </param>
                </xsl:when>




                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                </xsl:otherwise>

            </xsl:choose>

        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="replace-string">

        <xsl:param name="text" />
        <xsl:param name="replace" />
        <xsl:param name="with" />

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$with" />
                <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text"
                        select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$with" />
                </xsl:call-template>

            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**NOTE:**

In my XSLT I am initially searching if there are any line feeds. If there are any then I am replacing with white space.

In the same way I have added new code to search for `&quot;` . If I find any then I want to replace it with backslash quote (\").

When I try to execute this the error I am getting

**Error:**

The attribute 'name' cannot be added after child nodes or before an element is produced; it will be ignored.

Can someone please let me know what mistake I am doing.

**Expected output:**

```
<xyz>
    <param name="test" value="center at \&quot;St.\&quot; francisco ">
 </xyz>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Within your `xsl:choose`, the first `xsl:when` creates a `param` element, then creates the `name` and `value` attributes. However, the second `xsl:when` tries to create the same attributes without creating the `param` element first.

As a result, the stylesheet tries to assign these attributes to the parent node (`vce`) - but that one already has child nodes due to your `xsl:apply templates` instruction.

---

### Added:

To replace line-feeds with a space and quotes with an escaped quote, you only need to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@value[contains(., '&quot;') or contains(., '&#10;')]">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="translate(., '&#10;', ' ')" />
            <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&quot;'" />
            <xsl:with-param name="with" select="'\&quot;'" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="replace-string">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="replace" />
    <xsl:param name="with" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$with" />
            <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
                <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$with" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Test input:**

```
<xyz>
    <param name="test" value="center at &quot;St.&quot; francisco&#10;second line"/>
</xyz>
```

**Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xyz>
  <param name="test" value="center at \&quot;St.\&quot; francisco second line"/>
</xyz>
```

Comment: I am creating param only when the condition is met. If my XML doesn't have line feed and it has only quote then it shouldn't be a problem right?

Comment: @user2748161 I am afraid I don't entirely follow. I am quite sure that the source of the error is where I said it was. Other than that, I have a feeling your stylesheet is much more complex than it needs to be and I am not really wiling to go into it in depth - esp. since I don't understand what are you trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I know it is little tricky that is the reason why I have written steps.
If my XML has line feeds then I am replacing with white space. If you see replace-string is a generic template which expects params. I just need to send `text` and what to `replace` it `with`. 
Now if my xml has `&quote;` I want to repace it with `\&quote;\

Comment: What you wrote as your goal - just replacing the characters - should be much simpler than that.

Comment: @user2748161 See the addition to my answer.